# Save Date variable by RandomAccesFile

Tags: java

How can I write a date variable using `RandomAccesFile` in Java? I know a date variable is 7 bytes, but I don't know how to write it.

Comment: "I know Date var is 7 bytes" - in what way? Fundamentally, a `Date` just wraps a `long`, which is 8 bytes...

Comment: Sorry, I am wrong. But I have the same problem, how can I write it?

Comment: It sounds like you have two tasks: 1) Convert the `Date` to a `byte[]`. 2) Write the `byte[]` to a `RandomAccessFile`. Now, do you know how to do *either* of those?

Answer (score 0):

Here is some example how to work with `Date` and files.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.*;

public class DateExample {

     public static void main(String []args) throws IOException, ParseException {
        /* convert string to Date */
        String time = "May 08 2015 05:19:34";
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        Date outDate = df.parse(time);

        /* write to file */
        System.out.println(outDate + " in one number is " + outDate.getTime());
        RandomAccessFile outFile = new RandomAccessFile("date-file", "rw");
        outFile.write(ByteBuffer.allocate(8).putLong(outDate.getTime()).array());
        outFile.close();

        /* read from file */
        Date inDate = new Date(); 
        RandomAccessFile inFile = new RandomAccessFile("date-file", "r");
        long t = inFile.readLong();
        inDate.setTime(t);
        outFile.close();
        System.out.println("number " + t + " is "+ inDate);
     }

}
```